# Terminal speaking in tongues after curl command

Tags: command-line, downloads, curl, output, binary

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 through the Oracle VirtualBox. I'm trying to install a Python environment Anaconda through the Terminal.

Following the instructions on [How To Install the Anaconda Python Distribution on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04), I came to:

```
curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

This is when my terminal started speaking in tongues with sample output:

```
"n�� ء�Q�6� �6                                                      p%�W��� �{K+� �ϧ_� 9��
             ��]6��=<h���Y/{��$[�g ��c
                                       Y }��Z���csoH8�S��mJ�Q���6�� #��;�c�����w �<X�-�xr�ӷsk���]�v�E9ۭlZ�D/q�V��t�il1]��:ު���j9^u� y ��r��~�[ş�ǯ7]�*k"3S�,�R�'� �F��� �bj�(�Du�LTҀtG;JK���-aQ�{ �ȗ)��}� ���- Ws �T+��j�'�]� ��U6 ���i� �6�(���ki����V�AZ�[K��ȻpilA��� �|\ ;5s��2��XsV o��3D�
                                               t�T�En�n�
                                                        ��mp ����2������F��ܺ�l� 0�5����,�(e �
                                                                                             �Y�ݮ��Nx��vF��n�9�y�-�N���9E�..ʵ!�Dݵ�[̺�� ��8���+YΛ���,Ê
O�1l!��V��t��ڡ6� �T��݋��d�Y����v�� �� ق�z�D.Z�iv�%�+�9 o��-�͹�K(�n"�i�-�Y�Nm)1仕��|\�<��Ҹ���y�d ���;[ �ԡ�S��ΰ�>%�m,!��ݛ5#5����b~m��n��n)�ƨ�˧���1�m�y����94�i�(u� �����Y��_�i�=�
U���� �R֎(��fn Ui ȵ�'M|9��:
��j��9 6AJ*BԹ�� {3����A^ B�ٻ���*kE��3#��
                                        %�3X�S�I��2ؗDYUz1����q��}�| .Y�^sO    � ���q�al�R��Xt8ñt�֝ kë�21
                                                                                                         �D{���b�vkh�@��5(�$�KJ%��V� ��ޓ3teJ�# *r*��YWu�� Vcy�<�wWqm�Q�Ђt,�7 ���� bQ碟�eT\��,Q���= D,7=��ud�I5��UVd���E3�oC]��<� �܌�z��V���� }��� �l��]��P9 h6ծR�.��;����פ�þ �͜��ǡ�s7\ڙ���ZՙҰ�5Z��. �bh^� U^=������7-Dڏ� �y�9Z\:"�'l���(*�c� Y��ҳ� 3�v\���_ "�� f�\K]��e��� /b��9���^��G 0�� tw�Ef�:� @��! 
                                             U�� �*�a���>l ���iڨ$��u1�K
                                                                       Z�� j�q �ӧ4��n���&��>ԃZj �s��׳���f��hqօ�Ȓ�Nv(\f����4[S֎^ui$�.Ju�ifZ�)@��k�T1ɭz�Ս�ʥ `�h�k����մ�Q�2�ŉ ض��^lmXֻǿ�k�;E� ��ڠ��
K��Ǹ�Y �����k~�ڵ9"�j� 7��"5�P�jJ�Q�Ƶ(�ؠ�m��Teoe�3"��xfqrl����
                                                             NE��q�
                                                                   Qc
                                                                     d�]�zZu�n� �|�Ge���6��\��d*k<���S�m��He�ɿ����ǯq=�f�V ���i]�
          0˙�E�.g�c ��n� ��A�� ���r��� ��hW�p�Ԏ ���S �Lh�F�~�E'G^�l6;37����S4=    �� �S:� � ��Bc�ҧ�q� ҹ_����&� 2� �X 4�S �֛L� y���o tޱG��rzBn��*� X��� �*U=�;�^1�?��l�j��Z�    � ��� {4�x��6e � Nt-����|�i�݇��3S[�M)����͠�TdcC��*����-Y�;�� &2^*��ʶ�W��1�Wu�]�x3��" TX���E�Y%j�6`w����ON�0\��D5����&�Y<���a��� ym�����B�-� ��$_y���x�$����V��11Һ�
                   m�Ev�� 1^U� ��QM�Vz� <����56�9�F�� Wf��j�9���)�|v �u9%W
m-��8�(���hg�   ���]�Z� ���z�n�6 ��vk                                      mkj-��aA�\\a
                                     ��oޑr����oLт �65�<-r �uٻ�pq=�{� ���.NL^���
                                                                               ��� ��éV>~8 �c7Jw 5�y nG��[\W���f�I���[/�k��EfEa���8 z� �+�� ������y���    `�Nm.K|� �:L;SwY�������Ћ����ü�{� 65"� }> �kLW�F&b�K'(ihg�{� x�
                                                                                                       �4QJJ���9 �8Oj6�Z��:�
      �y,1�5�w�R

p�Ў���XqǊ 5t��1)u�ٟ��4 �J��hi��A !������kJ V\    ��� a�-a�R��A� ���$�f�k87��˾��O��f�j�N�XBzF�I�ɫ ��|.]^�K�W�s>U �
��a��κ��� ��� �ԡJ6X��,���충���Y��n�{ � g����E��~� ��t2g�θ����P����N�7:|S�`Z-+׮�O��Iѷ�������ZE��m�le�6��t����-^lU�)_��48R���j��I�h�L���J0&8Y��t� :aI�0n 
                                  � L��$V��� �=F W=�.t�˳*�h���Fm˱��Ծ}Qv��: �e��| �����^C"
```

Am I missing fonts here? I've talked to Prof. Google and I haven't come across anything that can help.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the option as `-O` (upper case letter O) not `-0` (digit zero)?

Comment: Looks like a binary file. Just close the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: just use the `reset` command.  LOL @ tongues :)

Comment: LOL yep. That's it. I was using a 0 (zero) instead of an O. Silly goose.
Thanks steeldriver and bodhu.zazen

Answer (score 5):

This is a [common problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50752/how-to-fix-a-terminal-after-a-binary-file-has-been-dumped-inside-it) due to [`curl`'s default behavior](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2014/11/17/why-curl-defaults-to-stdout/) of writing to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) unless told to do otherwise. The problem [will likely become less common](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2017/06/17/curl-doesnt-spew-binary-anymore/) as the newest versions of `curl` become more widely adopted.

The reason the problem happens is that binary files frequently contain sequences of characters that are interpreted as [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

As [guiverc says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959087/terminal-speaking-in-tongues-after-curl-command#comment1531923_959087), **typing `reset` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is usually sufficient to fix this.** It may be useful to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a few times first, because if you had accidentally typed anything else into the terminal, you might not know about it because the terminal isn't displaying things properly.

Sometimes `reset` doesn't work. You can try **running `stty sane` followed by `tput rs1`**, which [should work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79686/11938).

*References and Further Reading*

- [Fix terminal after displaying a binary file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/fix-terminal-after-displaying-a-binary-file)
- [How to fix a terminal after a binary file has been dumped inside it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50752/how-to-fix-a-terminal-after-a-binary-file-has-been-dumped-inside-it)
- [How to avoid escape sequence attacks in terminals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/how-to-avoid-escape-sequence-attacks-in-terminals)
  (Though *usually* when binary data messes up your terminal, it's accidental and harmless.)